# What is this meta content property og?

Tags: html, metadata

I was looking at the source code for a web page and this is the 3rd time I've seen this in the header:

```
<meta content="http://www.example.com/cmswp/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/01/something.jpg" property="og:image">
```

What is this and what is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is meta data for [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/)

By `og:image` you can provide an image URL which should represent your object within the graph.

> The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object
>   in a social graph. For instance, this is used on Facebook to allow any
>   web page to have the same functionality as any other object on
>   Facebook.
>
> While many different technologies and schemas exist and could be
>   combined together, there isn't a single technology which provides
>   enough information to richly represent any web page within the social
>   graph. The Open Graph protocol builds on these existing technologies
>   and gives developers one thing to implement. Developer simplicity is a
>   key goal of the Open Graph protocol which has informed many of the
>   technical design decisions.

---

Basically these meta tags will be used by social networks to represent your web page anywhere they need.

Visit the following site to see how Facebook interpret `og` meta tags in real time and create an object that represent a page. Try google.com in it.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Ah I see. ...What is a graph? Is this just a way to describe the web page content?

Comment: The concept of social graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_graph. And you can make your website an object of this graph by providing `og` meta tags. You define through these meta tags how your website is represented in the graph.

Comment: I added more information to the answer for you to understand it better.

Comment: Ah I see. ...so it benefits Facebook and other entities that are trying to represent my webpage and the "data" I'm presenting?

Comment: Should I use this on my website? Do you use it on your website?

Comment: I think it is a benefit for any web page to be properly represented in the social graph. Social media users will get a better idea about your website at the site of it.

Answer (score 1):

The [open graph protocol](http://ogp.me/):

> The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph. For instance, this is used on Facebook to allow any web page to have the same functionality as any other object on Facebook.